# PHP trim function removing last character

Tags: php, trim

I ran into a weird issue with php trim function.

```
<?php
$str = "New Multan Nagar";
$trimmedStr = trim($str, ' \t\n\r\0\x0B');
var_dump($trimmedStr);// output => string(15) "New Multan Naga"

$str = "New Multan Nagar";
$trimmedStr = trim($str, " \t\n\r\0\x0B");
var_dump($trimmedStr); // output => string(16) "New Multan Nagar"
?>
```

Second parameter value is default value used by trim function, only difference is that one is inside single quotes and other inside double quotes.
Can anyone explain this behavior?

Comment: Learn about when to use strings in single quotes, and in double quotes [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php). This is not weird at all if you read the manual and understand the differences; and the PHP Docs are pretty clear on the differences

Comment: @mark-baker Thanks for the help.  I did know the difference between single quotes and double quotes but when I came across this issue, somehow I was just thinking about variable substitution and completely ignored escape characters :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

php will not recognise slash(`/`) characters when using single quotes. Only when they are wrapped in double quotes they will be seen as special characters.

So in your case the single quoted version is removing all `tnrx0B` characters.

Answer (score 0):

The difference is Single Quote and Double Quote, See [Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.single)

Single Quote: It output exactly whats inside.

Double Quote: It will interpret before output.